# Combining CheckBoxColumn and TextColumn into one column

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

Is it possible to combine a `DataGridTextColumn` and `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` into one column?

I have this class where I combine two columns values into one result:

```
public class ViewQuoteItemList
{
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public bool TrueFalse { get; set; }

    public string CheckBoxColumn
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Supplier, TrueFalse); }
    }
}
```

Then I bind one of the columns like this:

```
DataGridTextColumn columnFeedbackSupplier = new DataGridTextColumn();
columnFeedbackSupplier.Binding = new Binding("CheckBoxColumn");
```

I do not know how to bind/join a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTextColumn` to display both the text and a checkbox in one column

Comment: Have you look into DataGridTemplateColumn??

Comment: Yes I have but I could not find any information on how I could combine both types into one column

Comment: you could define a CellTemplate for the same using DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit more detail? 0_o

Comment: Also, how can I then bind that `DataGridTemplateColumn` in code behind? I know it's a bit more difficult than a normal TextColumn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridTemplateColumn` you can define Template for the same.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ViewQuote">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Supplier}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TrueFalse}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Great stuff! Thank you very much Abhinav! Also is there a way to bind a Tempelate column the same as you did in XAML, but do it in C# code?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754608/what-is-the-code-behind-for-datagridtemplatecolumn-and-how-to-use-it) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779893/create-datagridtemplatecolumn-through-c-sharp-code) are some links to get you started.

Comment: Also please don`t forget to mark it as answer.Thanks